# C++ "Importing" an enum class from another C++ file

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

I'm a coming from a Java background so please bear with me on this :)

I'm trying to "import" (to use Java terminology) an `enum class` from another C++ file so as to be able to use it directly without having to prefix it with the class name.

So for instance, let's say I have this in a header file:

```cpp
class Foo
{
    public:
        enum class Bar {ITEM_1, ITEM_2};
        void doThings(Bar bar);
};
```

Now, currently, if I want to use `Bar` from another C++ file, I do this:

```cpp
#include "Foo.h"

void Foo2::methodInAnotherFile()
{
    Foo foo();
    Foo::Bar bar = Foo::Bar::ITEM_2;
    foo.doThings(bar);
}
```

Now what I'd like to do is to be able to do something like "import" (to use Java terminology) `Bar` so as to be able to remove the need to prefix `Bar` with `Foo::`, i.e. do `Bar bar = Bar::ITEM_2;`.

Now, with my limited knowledge of C++, one way I can think of doing this would be to surround all the code in `Foo.h` with `namespace FooNamespace{}`, take the `Bar` enum out of the class (but still in the namespace), and then add `using namespace FooNamespace` to the top of the `Foo2` class. However, for my application that really doesn't make much logical sense, as the `Bar` enum really logically belongs inside that `Foo` class.

Since I'm proficient in Java, here's a Java example of what I'd like to do:

File 1:

```java
package org.fooclass;

public class Foo
{
    public static enum Bar
    {
        ITEM_1,
        ITEM_2;
    }

    public void doThings(Bar bar)
    {
        System.out.println("Item: " + bar.toString());
    }
}
```

File 2:

```java
package org.foo2class;

import org.fooclass.Foo;
import org.fooclass.Foo.Bar; //I want to do THIS in C++

public class Foo2
{
    public void methodInAnotherFile()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        /*
         * Since I've 'imported' Foo.Bar, I can now
         * use Bar directly instead of having to do this:
         * Foo.Bar bar = Foo.Bar.ITEM2;
         */
        Bar bar = Bar.ITEM_2;

        foo.doThings(bar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) via a `using` statement, eg:

```cpp
#include "Foo.h"

using Bar = Foo::Bar; // <-- here

void Foo2::methodInAnotherFile()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar = Bar::ITEM_2;
    foo.doThings(bar);
}
```

Or, to limit its scope:

```cpp
#include "Foo.h"

void Foo2::methodInAnotherFile()
{
    using Bar = Foo::Bar; // <-- here
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar = Bar::ITEM_2;
    foo.doThings(bar);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and I get this compile error: `'Foo' is not a namespace or unscoped enum`

Comment: Correct, it is a class name. Use type aliasing instead. 'using Bar1 = Foo::Bar;'